# Make NSTableView active

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

Cocoa noob here.

I've got a simple Mac app that includes an NSTextField that fetches some results and puts them into an NSTableView. I'd like to be able to press up/down while in the text field to activate the first/last item in the table view.

I've done the following:

```
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    switch([theEvent keyCode]) {
        case 125: {
            NSLog(@"I need to move down");
            NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
            [resultsTableView selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
            [resultsTableView becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }
        case 126: {
            NSLog(@"I need to move up");
            NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[results count]-1];
            [resultsTableView selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
            [resultsTableView becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is partially what I want. It does select the first or last item in the `resultsTableView`, but the selected item stays grayed out, and the textview stays active.

I thought calling `becomeFirstResponder` on the `resultsTableView` would do the trick, but it didn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never call `becomeFirstResponder` directly.  Use NSWindow's `makeFirstResponder:`

```
[[resultsTableView window] makeFirstResponder:resultsTableView];
```

Comment: I just ran into this, any ideas why we have to make the call via the window rather than the responder its self?

Comment: [Because Apple said so](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/becomeFirstResponder) `becomeFirstResponder` "Never invoke this method directly."